# Problem with "Verify & Publish Contract Source Code" on BscScan

Tags: remix, contract-design, verify, contract-verification, bscscan

I wanted to "Verify & Publish Contract Source Code" on BscScan, but I get this message:

ParserError: Multiple SPDX license identifiers found in source file. Use "AND" or "OR" to combine multiple licenses. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.
--> myc

What should I do? I am new to this and the source code is from github

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do is removing all `SPDX license identifiers` and `pragma solidity`, then keeping only 1 `SPDX license identifiers` and `pragma solidity` on the top of the file.